# php and google maps api

Tags: php, html, google-maps

New to coding but had an idea to make my life easier at work - maybe I am being too ambitious!!!

I found some code that allows to to show push pins on a google map that are placed within the code via a variable - postcode- I need to pass postcodes from an excel csv file into the code and then display this on the map.

the original code is  NOT mine but I am pasting here to show the basis on my query.
 This is not PHP but felt I wanted to use PHP to link to excel - if this is wrong please feel free to point me in the right direction!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Geocoding Simple</title>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/standard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    var markers = [];
    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.768505,-111.853244);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            addPostCode ('BA2 3RA');
        addPostCode ('BN1 1AB');
        addPostCode ('BA3 3JG');
           }

    function addPostCode(zip) {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zip}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            name: zip
        });
        markers.push(marker);
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
        });
    }

    function checkZip(zip)
    {
        var distance = Number.MAX_VALUE;
        var index = 0;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zip}, function(results, status)
        {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            {
                for(ix=0; ix< markers.length; ix++)
                {
                    var tmp = getDistance(results[0].geometry.location, markers[ix].position);
                    if (tmp < distance)
                    {
                        distance = tmp;
                        index = ix;
                    }
                }
                alert('nearest zipcode is :' + markers[index].name);
            }
        });
    }

    function getDistance(latlng1, latlng2)
    {
        var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
        var dLat = (latlng2.lat()-latlng1.lat()) * Math.PI / 180;  // Javascript functions in radians
        var dLon = (latlng2.lng()-latlng1.lng()) * Math.PI / 180;
        var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(latlng1.lat()  * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(latlng2.lat()  * Math.PI / 180) *
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
        var d = R * c; // Distance in km
        d = d * 0.621371192; // convert to miles
        return d;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div>
    <input id="address" type="textbox" value="">
    <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="checkZip(getElementById('address').value)">
  </div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:90%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) An excel file is of .xsl or .xsls extension.  csv is another file type that is readable in excel. 

2) To access the csv data use an ajax function to the php code you use. To retrieve csv data in php, there is a function called fgetcsv() in php, read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fgetcsv.asp

3) Don't expect us to write code for you, tell us what you have done, except from copying someone else's code here, and tell us the results and your issue. I'll be glad to help.

4) You don't have a question here, AFAI can see.

Comment: Apologies if I sounded like I just wanted you to provide a full solution - that is not my intention - I have adapted the above code slightly to suit my needs  but am struggle to read a csv file that contains about 10 postcodes only - i need where this code shows       addPostCode ('BN1 1AB');   that it pulls in the postcodes from the csv file assumed it is possible as most things are but was struggling to get to an answer - i will keep persevering :)

Comment: Again, it is not clear, do you want to replace `addPostCode ('BN1 1AB');` with results from your csv file data?

Comment: Can you explain how you get csv data from php and how you get those results to javascript? Without that, It's hard for me to get an idea

Comment: i have a csv file from a database query - the file will contain for example ba2 3ra,bn1 1at,bn4 3at     I then wish to import those values onto a google map to show their locations - i have tried fgetcsv  - which does give me an array - i need to pass those values to the google maps api - this is where I am stuck - from your question yes i wan to replace the "BN1 1AB with value 1 from csv file then next row be BN! 2AB for example until all of the csv file has been added then display on the map

Comment: see if you get an error that says that `results[0].geometry.location` is not a latLng literal? or any other error in the console

Comment: or have you got that far? if you haven't please put the array you get from php here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you've got as far as getting the CSV data into a PHP array. So the next step is to pass that to a JavaScript array. To do this we rely on the fact that, in any .php file that contains a mixture of HTML markup and PHP code (the HTML of course being outside `<?php .... ?>` tags and the PHP inside them), at runtime the PHP interpreter goes through the file FIRST and processes the PHP. So if you have an echo statement in the PHP, it will echo whatever's being echoed into the HTML, which is then parsed as HTML markup with whatever values were written into it. Note how we can even have a PHP loop going on around HTML (or in this case Javacript embedded in the HTML), all because the PHP gets processed before anything else!

So in a .php script do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php

include "getCsvData.php";   // this is where you put the data into a PHP array called $dataArray;
// now we exit the PHP and do the HTML including our Javascript...

?>
[HTML head code here]
<body>
[more HTML markup here, we usually put javascripts at the end]

<script>
var markers = [];   // your javascript array

<?php 
// start a loop in the PHP
for( $i=0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
// then back to the javascript...
?>
arr[<?php echo $i;?>] = <?php echo $dataArray[$i]; ?>;  // note the final semi-colon ; here

<?php } ?>
</script>
```

So that's it (hope I haven't got any typos there, apologies if I have, you'll need to test it out). Once you have it working if you display the web page in your browser and right click on it and choose the browser's "Source code" option, you will see the <script> tags have magically gained 10 lines of javascript code adding the array values. (I used 10 for convenience in this example, you'll need to find out how big your PHP data array is using count()).

Don't forget that last little line of php to close the php loop - it's just a single close curly bracket inside PHP tags. Note also the doctype line needs to be the first line in the file.

Finally, since you're new to Google Maps and just found that bit of code to work from, be sure to go to the Google API documentation at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial - it's very clear. Yes, as you say, you're certainly ambitious, but that's good and it will all be an excellant introduction into PHP coding and Google Maps as well. All the best with it!

Comment: GuyMany thanks for this and your words of encouragement its really appreciated - I will report back!! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what has worked for me - dont know if it will help anyone ( needs tidying up!!) but hope it will one day!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php
include "getCsvData.php";
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Geocoding Simple</title>
    <link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/standard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var geocoder;
        var map;
        var markers = [];

        function initialize() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.768505,-111.853244);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            <?php
        for($i = 0, $j = count($dataArray); $i < $j-1 ; $i++) {
        ?>
            addPostCode(<?php echo str_replace( array( '[', ']'), '', json_encode($dataArray[$i])); ?>);
            <?php } ?>
        }
        function addPostCode(zip) {
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zip}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        name: zip
                    });
                    markers.push(marker);
                } else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
            });
        }

        function checkZip(zip)
        {
            var distance = Number.MAX_VALUE;
            var index = 0;
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zip}, function(results, status)
            {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                {
                    for(ix=0; ix< markers.length; ix++)
                    {
                        var tmp = getDistance(results[0].geometry.location, markers[ix].position);
                        if (tmp < distance)
                        {
                            distance = tmp;
                            index = ix;
                        }
                    }
                    alert('nearest zipcode is :' + markers[index].name);
                }
            });
        }

        function getDistance(latlng1, latlng2)
        {
            var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
            var dLat = (latlng2.lat()-latlng1.lat()) * Math.PI / 180;  // Javascript functions in radians
            var dLon = (latlng2.lng()-latlng1.lng()) * Math.PI / 180;
            var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                Math.cos(latlng1.lat()  * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(latlng2.lat()  * Math.PI / 180) *
                Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
            var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
            var d = R * c; // Distance in km
            d = d * 0.621371192; // convert to miles
            return d;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:90%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```